# Properties of a metric

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

- Suppose that we have the space $(C(0,1), \rho)$.

  Then we can define a metric but this won't come from a norm.

  Could you explain me the above proposition?
- Also I want to show that if $\rho(x,y)$ is a metric on $X$, then $\sigma(x,y)= \min \{ 1, \rho(x,y)\}$ is also a metric.

  The properties of a metric on $X$ are the following:

  1. $\rho(x,y) \geq 0, \forall x, y \in X$
  2. $\rho(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$
  3. $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$  $, \forall x,y \in X$
  4. $\rho(x,z) \leq \rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z), \forall x, y,z \in X$

  I have thought the following:

  If $\rho(x,y)<1$ then $\sigma(x,y)$ is trivially a metric, since $\sigma(x,y)=\rho(x,y)$.

  If $\rho(x,y)>1$ then $\sigma(x,y)=1$.

  Then the first property is satified since $1 \geq 0$.

  The third property is satisfies since $\sigma(x,y)= \sigma(y,x)=1$.

  The fourth property is also satisied since $\sigma(x,z)=1 \leq \sigma(x,z)+ \sigma(y,z)=2$.

  But $\sigma(x,y)=0$ is never satisfied, so also not or $x=y$.

  So how can $\sigma(x,y)= \min \{ 1, \rho(x,y)\}$ be a metric?

Comment: Consider replacing (analysis) with a more specific tag for the relevant branch of analysis. *(autocomment)*

Comment: I replaced it with real analysis and functional analysis. Are these more appropriate?

Comment: The title is unrelated to the question.

Comment: FWIW, the paragraph where the OP supposedly explains what they tried is an excellent example of the labyrinth one puts students in when one fails to make a distinction between a *function* and the *values* this function takes. The first absurd sentence in the post is "if $\rho(x,y)$ is a metric on $X$".

Answer (score 2):

The last property is satisfied. Indeed if $\sigma (x,y) = 0$ then we must have
$$\min \{ 1, \rho (x,y) \} = 0$$
Clearly we cannot have $1 = 0$ so we must have
$$ 0 = \min \{ 1, \rho (x,y) \} = \rho(x,y)$$
since $\rho$ is a metric then it follows that $x = y$. If $x = y$ then
$$ \sigma(x,y) = \min \{ 1, \rho (x,y) \} = \min \{ 1, 0\} = 0$$
as desired.

Comment: Ah I see.. so we don't have to take cases. We can also show the other properties so that $\sigma(x,y)$ is a metric as follows:

$$\sigma(x,y) = \min \{ 1, \rho(x,y) \}\geq 0, \forall x,y \in X, \text{ since } 1 \geq 0 \text{ and } \rho(x,y) \text{ is a metric}$$

$$\sigma(x,y)= \min \{ 1, \rho(x,y) \} = \min \{ 1, \rho(y,x) \} = \sigma(y,x)$$

$$\sigma(x,z)= \min \{ 1, \rho(x,z)\} \leq \min \{ 2, \rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)\} \leq \min \{ 1, \rho(x,y) \}+ \min \{ 1, \rho(y,z) \}= \sigma(x,y)+ \sigma(y,z)$$


Or is something wrong?

Comment: No nothing is wrong, that is just right!

Comment: Nice, thank you!!! @Kayleof theCreeks $$$$
Could you maybe also explain me why given the space $(C(0,1), \rho)$ we can define a metric but this won't come from a norm?

Comment: I am not too sure. I don't really understand your question, what "norm"?

Comment: Why is there  no norm that induces the metric?

Comment: @evinda The computation in your first comment is actually squarely wrong since the inequality $$\min(2,a+b)\leqslant\min(1,a)+\min(1,b)$$ is not guaranteed at all.